# Access a specific tag value in an XML response with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am calling a SOAP web service that returns an XML similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <SalidaConsultaSAF xmlns="http://wtp">
      <coderror>02</coderror>
      <dserror>No records</dserror>
    </SalidaConsultaSAF>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'mm trying to parse it in order to access the value of the tags `coderror` and `dserror`, but I'm just failing miserably all the time.

This is just one of the several approaches I've taken:

```
# parse XML response
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# call the web service
response = requests.post(url, auth=('myUser', 'myPass'),
                         verify=False, data=body, headers=headers)

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(response.content))

a_ = ET.Element(tree) # ==> {'attrib': {}, 'tag': <xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x7f4736e299d0>, '_children': []}

b_ = ET.SubElement(a_, 'coderror') # ==> {'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'soapenv', '_children': []}
```

As you can see, the value of variable `b` is "empty". I would like to obtain the string `02`.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.XML(response.content)
tree.findtext(".//{http://wtp}SalidaConsultaSAF/{http://wtp}coderror")
```

yields `'02'`.

[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much!!